# Create element from datatemplate if condition is true

Tags: wpf, xaml

I got a ItemsControl in my XAML.

In the < ItemsPanelTemplate > is a Grid

and in the < ItemsControl.ItemTemplate > is a Button.

I want to add the Button in the Grid only if a condition is true. What kind of triggers I have to use and where?

Comment: Only add an item to the ItemsSource collection if the item should be shown. Bind the Grid.Column and Grid.Row properties to properties of the item in an ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It sounds like you want the columns of this Grid all aligned, and the number of rows to automatically adjust to match the number of elements in the list? If so then ItemsControl isn't the best choice of control, you're much better off using DataGrid.